# redux-form: How to disable submit button if at least one Field is not valid?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm rendering the below simple form using redux-form and it's working nicely. Now, I'd like to have the submit button disabled in one more situation: If any of the `Field`'s has an error (i.e. it's `meta.error` is set).

From lokking into the docs, I suppose it is not possible for the surrounding `<form>` to know if its `<Field>` components have an error. Maybe anyone has an idea, how to solve it as easy as using `disabled={hasErrors || submitting || pristine}`

```js
const EditBlogEntryForm = ({ onSubmit, reset, handleSubmit,
                         pristine, submitting, ...rest }) => {
    console.log('rest: ', rest);
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <Field name="title"
                    type="text"
                    component={renderField}
                    label="Titel"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Titel eingeben..." />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <Field name="text"
                    component={renderTextArea}
                    label="Text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Textinhalt eingeben..." />
            </div>  
            <div className="form-group">
                <Field name="image"
                    type="text"
                    component={renderField}
                    label="Bild-URL:"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Bildadresse eingeben..." />
            </div>  
            <div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default"
                    disabled={submitting || pristine}>
                    Blogeintrag speichern
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default"
                    disabled={pristine || submitting}
                    onClick={reset}>
                    Formular leeren
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
};
```

Comment: what you can do is just add in your own variable and put it in the state like `Errors`. Once that value is false then you can hit the submit button

Answer (score 27):

Don't abuse state you need just using this.props
for each setState Component one more time will be render

```
const {invalid} = this.props

return(
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-default"
     disabled={invalid|| submitting || pristine}>
     Blogeintrag speichern
 </button>)
```

More Document:
https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/props.md/

Answer (score 3):

Redux forms already passes lots of properties into the form. One is `invalid`. That's what I am using to determine if any of the field validations failed and then disable submit.

https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/props.md/

Answer (score 2):

What you should be able to do is just have a variables called `Errors` that will be true once your api call comes back with an error

```
 constructor(super) {
      this.state = {
         errors: false,
      }
 }

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     const that = this;
     if (nextProps.errors) {
        that.setState({errors: true})
     }    
 }

 <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default"
     disabled={this.state.errors || submitting || pristine}>
     Blogeintrag speichern
 </button>
```

Comment: as mentioned by @masoud-soroush, better not abuse the state. See his [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47617564/1111215).

Answer (score 0):

Alastair pointed me into the correct direction (Thanks for that!). I guess this is one of the cases where a local UI-related state is actually very useful. So I refactored the SFC into a react class. That classes' `constructor` and `componentWillReceiveProps` look like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        errors: false
    };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.invalid) {
        this.setState({errors: true});
    } else {
        this.setState({errors: false});
    }
}
```

Now using `this.state.errors` to have the button disabled is working perfectly. As you can see, I had to use the `invalid` prop form redux-form, because its `error` prop was always undefined and not to forget to set it true again, if the form is valid. Furthermore I don't know, why you copied the `this` reference into `that` in your answer. It wouldn't change any behaviour as it's still pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `react-redux-form` library you can eventually use the `onUpdate` event on the form to capture the validity state of the form and like this you can change some internal state variable which can be used to deactivate a button. Here is some sample code to demonstrate what you can do:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, Row, Label, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { Control, LocalForm, Errors } from 'react-redux-form';

const required = (val) => val && val.length;

const maxLength = (len) => (val) => !(val) || (val.length <= len);

const minLength = (len) => (val) => (val) && (val.length >= len);

class CommentForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isModalOpen: false,
            isFormInValid: true
        };
        this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
    }

    toggleModal() {
        this.setState({
            isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(values) {
        console.log("Current state is: " + JSON.stringify(values));
        alert(JSON.stringify(values));
    }

    handleUpdate(form) {
        this.setState({ isFormInValid: !form['$form'].valid });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Button outline onClick={this.toggleModal}>
                    <span className="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></span> Submit Comment
                </Button>
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} toggle={this.toggleModal}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleModal}>Submit Comment</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <LocalForm
                            onUpdate={(form) => this.handleUpdate(form)}
                            onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
                            <Row className="form-group">
                                <Label htmlFor="author" md={12}>Your Name</Label>
                                <Col md={12}>
                                    <Control.text model=".author" id="author" name="author"
                                        placeholder="First Name" className="form-control"
                                        validators={{ required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(15) }} />
                                    <Errors className="text-danger" model=".author" show="touched"
                                        messages={{ required: 'Required ', minLength: 'Must be greater than 2 characters', maxLength: 'Must be 15 characters or less' }} />
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                            <Row className="form-group">
                                <Col md={12}>
                                    <Button type="submit" color="primary" disabled={this.state.isFormInValid}>Submit</Button>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </LocalForm>
                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an update for Masoud Soroush's answer.

Checking the *invalid prop only* is enough.

```
const {invalid} = this.props

return(
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-default"
     disabled={invalid}>
     Blogeintrag speichern
</button>
```

Note: Use the submitting prop only if you have passed an onSubmit function that returns a promise. It will be true until the promise is resolved or rejected.

Answer (score -2):

A possibility is to use validate field. You need to defined a function :

`const required = value => (value ? undefined : 'Required')`

And use this function in your field :

```
           <div className="form-group">
                <Field name="title"
                    type="text"
                    component={renderField}
                    label="Titel"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Titel eingeben..."
                    validate={[required]}
                />
            </div>
```

Comment: This suggestion is taken from the docs and does not provide a complete solution.